# Find the transform

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, signal-processing, projective-geometry

I have the paper with 3 points on it. I have also a photo of this paper. How can I determine where is the paper on the photo, if I know just the positions of these points? And are 3 points enough?
It doesn't look like a linear transform: the paper turns into trapeze on the photo. But it should be able to be written mathematically. I was unsuccessfully looking for some function $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, which turns the coordinates of the points on the default paper to their coordinates on photo, so I could just apply this function to the paper corners, but I have no idea, what kind of transform it should be.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Well the problem is "trapeze" doesn't name a specific figure. Are you folding it into a pyramid? A cone? A frustum? A tetrahedron?

Comment: The paper is the standard A4 rectangle. Yes, it doesn't turn into the precise trapeze, it is just the quadrangle.

Comment: I mean what is the figure that it turns into, because "trapeze" isn't a figure.

Comment: Maybe you are a projective transformation, assuming that there is a point in the camera behind the film and that a straight line is drawn from that point through the film (image) to the original object? But then two corresponding pairs of points would give a pair of intersecting lines ...

Comment: Yes, it should be exactly the projective transformation! Wiki expains only the case with two cameras. Is it really nessesary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a projective transformation is exactly right. But with a projective transformation you can take any four points in general position (no three collinear) to any other four. So you'd better add a fourth point to reconstruct the transformation.

In terms of the linear algebra, you want to construct a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$, up to scalar multiples. You think of a point in $\mathbb R^2$ as a vector $X=\begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\y\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^3$ and its image will be the vector $AX$ rescaled so that its first coordinate is likewise $1$. So see that you can determine $A$ from knowing where *four* points map, think of it this way. A linear map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ is determined by where it sends a basis. Given our three points in general position, they correspond to vectors $P$, $Q$, $R\in\mathbb R^3$ up to scaling. 
But now, given our fourth point in general position, we can rescale those vectors so that the fourth point is given by $P+Q+R$. Doing the corresponding construction with the four image points will now allow us to specify precisely where $A$ sends our basis vectors, up to one common scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thank you! But how does look this transform look? Suppose I have four 2D points and their four 2D images. The matrix $2\times 4$ and its image, in other words. What then? Is the transform itself some matrix multiplication?

Comment: I've edited. See if that helps. It's probably good to use some actual numbers and work out an example :) If we put two of the points at infinity (which isn't practical in your case), we could use $P=(1,0,0)$, $Q=(0,1,0)$, and $R=(0,0,1)$ — thus, the standard basis vectors — and the gist should become clear. But, with a bit more mess, you can use the vertices of *any* triangle in the form $(1,*,*)$.

Comment: I'll try to implement this in my algorithm tomorrow, I believe this is what I need. Anyway, accepting you answer now)

Comment: Let me know if you need more assistance. This is stuff that most math students don't learn anymore. :(